# Where is template for "Qt Widgets application" in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt-creator

I want to customize this template and I cann't find it. qtcreator/templates/wizards/projects folder contains only cpp and c plain projects, qtquick templates, and some other templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For historical reasons the Qt Widgets Application wizard template is located in `share/qtcreator/templates/qt4project/` (or `Qt Creator.app/Contents/Resources/templates/qt4project/` if you happen to be on macOS).